How to get Segwit address from OKX wallet
I am going to connect OKX wallet in my bitcoin based game app and have one problem in getting native segwit address from okx wallet. I read their developer doc and there are two way to get address. https://www.okx.com/web3/build/docs/sdks/chains/bitcoin/provider
const result = await okxwallet.bitcoin.connect()

let accounts = await okxwallet.bitcoin.requestAccounts();

both return taproot address and I can't get native segwit and other types of address when user connect wallet.

I have read the doc you posted here, and yes, there are no parameters about the address type, so maybe it defaults to return the segwit address. Maybe you can propose an issue to the dev team to add a new address type parameter.

I sent email but no response, and their support chat is AI chat. not helped for me

https://github.com/okx/js-wallet-sdk/blob/main/packages/coin-bitcoin/src/wallet/BtcWallet.ts#L96

I found the related code in their bitcoin wallet code, and there actually is the address type param to choose from, but it does not exist in the okx wallet doc.
